# SQL Query WHERE clause gives errors

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query and it is rather advanced for me. I have a table add_design with two columns status and home, so I want to add a part WHERE status=1 and home='Yes' in the query. I just don't understand where to put it. Can someone breakdown the query for me please?

```sql
SELECT mytable.*, CONCAT(fname, ' ',  lname) AS user_name, user.image AS user_image, 
    user.fname, user.lname, add_design_doc.image as product_image 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        add_design.id, add_design.user_id,  title, category, COUNT(add_design.user_id) AS total_likes 
    FROM 
        add_design INNER JOIN 
        like_unlike ON (add_design.id = like_unlike.product_id AND
                        like_unlike.type = '1')
    GROUP BY 
        add_design.id 
    ORDER BY
        total_likes DESC ) AS mytable INNER JOIN 
    
    user ON mytable.user_id = user.id LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    add_design_doc ON mytable.id = add_design_id
GROUP BY
    user_id LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: You have this JOIN clause in your query: "FROM add_design 
INNER JOIN like_unlike ON (add_design.id = 
like_unlike.product_id AND like_unlike.type = '1' AND $where_clause_15days 
$where_clause)". Just extend this by adding your conditions AND add_design.status = 1 AND add_design.home='Yes'

Comment: is `$where_clause_15days $where_clause` even valid?

Comment: @T.S. I'm using the SQL statement in PHP and that is a PHP variable, so yes.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Thank you, I understand how the statement is working now.

Comment: @consolenine then post questions properly. Use proper tags, etc. Thanks